# spektral.datasets.citation.load_data() not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, graph-neural-network

I am trying to use the CoRA dataset to train a graph neural network on tensorflow and it's my first time using Spektral.

After some research on the internet, I learnt that there's supposed to be a useful loader function that comes with Spektral for me to load this benchmark dataset so I attempted to implement it:

```
adj,features,labels,train_mask,val_mask,test_mask=spektral.datasets.citation.load_data(dataset_name="cora")
```

Then I got this:

```
AttributeError: module 'spektral.datasets.citation' has no attribute 'load_data'
```

I checked the Spektral documentation and I didn't find the `load_data` loader function so I think there's an update or something.

It would be helpful if anybody can provide any alternatives or a possible explanation for the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved the problem myself after some more research. For Spektral version 1.1.0, I think this does the job of the loader function in terms of using the CoRA dataset:

```
cora_dataset = spektral.datasets.citation.Citation(name='cora')
test_mask = cora_dataset.mask_te
train_mask = cora_dataset.mask_tr
val_mask = cora_dataset.mask_va
graph = cora_dataset.graphs[0]
features = graph.x
adj = graph.a
labels = graph.y
```

Comment: How did you find out this usage? i just want to know the process of finding?

Comment: I kind of just looked through the documentation of Spektral where it mentions things about "cora". The documentation makes it clear about the mask attributes.